# Which one of $\|x\|\le1, \|x\|= 1, \|x\|\ge1$ defines a convex set?

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm trying to solve the following question but I'm stuck.

"Which of the following constraints define a convex set: ∥x∥ ≤ 1, ∥x∥ =
1, ∥x∥ ≥ 1?"

The way to check for convexity is basically the same in all there cases so I will use ∥x∥ ≤ 1 as an example.

What I think I am supposed to do is assume that if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are points in the set $S = \left\{ {x:∥x∥ ≤ 1}\right\}$ and then prove that $z = \alpha*x_1 + (1-\alpha)*x_2 $ is in S for all values of $0\leq\alpha\leq1$.

But my problem is I don't know how to do this. Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  You're checking if a fact about the norm is true, and it involves an inequality...  Perhaps triangle inequality?